# Why can't I properly locate Debian 8.1 on my BeagleBone Black?

Tags: debian, systemd, locale, arm

I was using the BBB (BeagleBone Black) for a while now but with Arch Linux. Now that Debian also supports systemd I decided to give it a try. So I followed [this guide](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardDebian#eMMC:_BeagleBone_Black) and used the eMMC flasher image to distribute a fresh debian on to the BBB.

After successfully rebooting I wanted to set my locale but all queries to localectl timed out. `systemctl status systemd-localed.service` revealed that the service entered a failed state.

The output says:

`Failed to read locale data: No such file or directory`

But nothing more. When looking into the journal with `journalctl -r -u systemd-localed.service`there is the same message but no clue about which file is missing.

Doing some research with `man systemd-localed` revealed two possible config files

> /etc/vconsole.conf

and

> /etc/locale.conf

Both files did not exist in the image but even after creating them with Google's guidance (as far as their content is concerned) the error persists.

Has anyone experienced a similar behavior of the Debian 8.1 image on the BBB? Or are there other known places where to look at those missing file?

Regards

Comment: Ubuntu Vivid doesn't have those two files, but running `localectl status` works.

Comment: I am running Debian 8.1, don't have these files neither and `localectl status` works as well. Try to run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root.

Comment: I made a reminder to try `dpkg-reconfigure locales` next time I have Debian 8.1 on the BBB if the error occurs again. Right now I switched back to ArchLinux. But many thanks anyways @JodkaLemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem:

The `systemd-localed` service launches the binary `/lib/systemd/systemd-localed`, which then tries to read `/etc/locale.conf`, `/etc/vconsole.conf` and — even though that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere — `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
# strace /lib/systemd/systemd-localed
[…]
open("/etc/locale.conf", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
[…]
open("/etc/vconsole.conf", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
[…]
open("/etc/default/keyboard", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
```

`/etc/default/keyboard` is usually generated by the `keyboard-configuration` package. You'll probably also want to install the "Linux console font and keytable utilities" in the `kbd` package and the keymaps from the `console-data` package:

```
apt-get install keyboard-configuration kbd console-data
dpkg-reconfigure console-data
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Since your system uses an ARM architecture, you will have to select your keymap from the "full" list when `console-data` is configured.

That will generate `/etc/default/keyboard` and allow `systemd-localed` to start and `localectl` to be used, even though it doesn't seem to recognize the keymaps installed with `console-data`. You can manually set something like `localectl set-keymap us-latin1`, but I couldn't check if that has any effect.

Also, while `localectl` shows the correct locale, it doesn't seem to be set globally, so `locale` still shows "POSIX" and programs like `tmux` and `htop` will still use ASCII.
I'm not sure if that's an actual Debian bug or just an effect of installing a system via `debootstrap` (like it is usually done to create SD card images for embedded boards) instead of running the full installer (which might automatically create some of those required files above).